# Ubuntu SSH client not connecting to VPS, however putty is?

Tags: ssh

I am using Ubuntu on my laptop, and am trying to SSH into my VPS with this command:

```
ssh root@liamwli.co.uk -p xxxx
```

(Port removed for security)

It doesn't connect however. If I add the `-vvv` command, I get this:

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to liamwli.co.uk [69.85.86.19] port xxxx.
debug1: connect to address 69.85.86.19 port xxxx: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host liamwli.co.uk port xxxx: Connection timed out
```

Why is it doing this? It works fine, and connects using putty on my Windows installation, so why doesn't it work using the built in ssh client on Ubuntu?

Comment: Make sure your port is forwarded properly on `69.85.86.19`. That is often the cause of timing out.

Comment: @htor It is a VPS, and I can connect using putty fine so I highly doubt that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot even get the ssh client to connect, you can rule out things like password/key auth, root logins, etc. Possible reasons why you cannot connect:

- Wrong port. Maybe you misread you PuTTY configuration.
- Locked out of your VPS because of too many failed connection attempts (firewall rules, Fail2ban)
- Port knocking daemon. Maybe your VPS firewall configuration requires you to send data to certain ports before the SSH ports opens. (not sure if PuTTY is that advanced though).
- VPN required. Perhaps you could connect to your VPS because it was tunnelled through a VPN connection which was activated on Windows, but not on Ubuntu.
- IP mismatch. Ensure that you are connecting to the same IP address. The IP address could change if you override it in `/etc/hosts` (or the Windows equivalent) or have a strange DNS server.
- Outbound blocking. You have a router that is very restrictive and had to add a rule for the Windows IP address to allow for connecting/forwarding to that SSH port. On your Linux installation, you got a different IP address.

Comment: +1. Most times it is one or several of this reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Normally (by default), SSH does not allow connection to **root**. This is a security feature, and should not be changed.

Have you tried to another user?