# Ssh client working in windows but not in linux

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I currently shifted to linux from windows but I can't connect to ssh when I use -vvv flag it shows connection timed out but in windows it just connects. I am coming from here [askubuntu.com/questions/240665](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240665/ubuntu-ssh-client-not-connecting-to-vps-however-putty-is) so please don't suggest me all the points I can guarantee that all the points are valid in my case. Please help me.

output of -vvv flag

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname myip is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to myip [myip] port myport.
debug1: connect to address myip port myport: Connection timed out
```

Comment: I suggest all questions need the version of Ubuntu being used.

Comment: Are both the windows and Ubuntu Linux client computers on the same network sub-net? Is that sub-net the same one that the Ubuntu Linux host computer is on? Can all 3 computers `ping` each other?

Comment: 1. Zorin Os 16 based on ubuntu is being used. |
2. I am unable to clarify I am just unable to connect with ssh from linux desktop and able to from windows. |
3. Yes they are on same network and no network issues at all I already added a link that tells that it's not problem with all that points.

Comment: Looks to me from the output that myip isn't available from your linux box.

Can you run traceroute for the ip and see where its going from both your Windoze and Linux boxes and compare?

Comment: @SimonBanks in my windows the trace begins but in linux I am getting this send: Operation not permitted what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 for faster dns lookups and after 30 hours of hard work I found that Cloudflare cli changes your ip also in linux so all I did was enabled dns only mode and everything is working fine now.